# Unwanted activation of Parental Controls on network accounts

Tags: network, mojave, user-account, parental-controls, active-directory

I am very confused about this issue and I don't know what to look for.

We are using MS Active Directory Accounts on our MacBooks. Since last week the parental controls were activated on all network accounts, but when we turn it off they are turned on again within a few hours.

Could it be, that there is a group policy that is applied on macOS devices that causes this issue?

Is there something else that I can look for?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!